# What to do when a user doesn't accept any answers?

Tags: discussion, voting, accepted-answer

I recently gave an answer (the one and only so far) and the OP stated in a comment that it works perfectly.

But he either upvoted nor accepted it.

I went to his profile and saw that he doesn't upvote or accept **at all**.

What can I do?

Flagging his question is a bad idea. Should I tell a moderator? But how?

Comment: You move on. Accepting answers is **never required**.

Comment: Nothing whatsoever. Accepting answers is not mandatory. Nor should you nag or badger users into accepting anything. It is how it is.

Comment: That's not my point. I mean: what to do with users when they never accept or upvote.

Comment: @joe You do nothing.  You keep answering questions.

Comment: If it bothers others that he won't accept answers, then he may get less help, but that's about the extent of what anyone can or should do.

Comment: [Ignorieren und weitermachen](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AyUsPCEgizw)

Comment: Well-written answers should receive upvotes, if not from the questioner, then from the community. If this doesn't happen, [Mr Community](http://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community) may push it to get more attention.

Comment: Note that if the user's reputation is sufficiently low, he _can't_ upvote answers.

Comment: My very first question ever on SO was this exact question.  And it got downvoted into oblivion.  Basically, I was told, "Move on".

Comment: You can mention like this, If one of the answers helped you, you can accept it. To accept an answer, you click the check mark (✓) that is placed to the left of the answer. In that way, other users will see what answer helped you most, and the users who answer will see that you've already found a solution. If none of the answers helped you, you should edit your question and explain why none of the answers solved your problem.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Nothing.

We can't force people to accept answer and we don't want to force them to do so.

An accept is an optional thing - it means that the answer selected was the one the OP found most helpful **if they care to do so**.

They might not accept answers because:

- They never came back
- No answer was exceptional for them
- They don't care to accept anything
- They don't know about accepting answers
- Beer

Comment: Well then...   Let's have a beer.

Comment: Sorry.  Had to edit your answer.  But I'm sure the edit will be rejected.  :oP

Comment: It's also worth noting that if we as answerers were driven purely by people accepting our answers, old questions whose askers haven't been seen in months or years would never go answered. You shouldn't answer a question just to help the OP, you should answer a question to help anyone who may stumble upon your answer in the future. If your answer is good enough quality it will be upvoted.

Answer (score 4):

If a user has not discovered the accept feature by now then you can leave a nice comment to make him/her aware of it.

#### But nobody has to accept anything.

So please don't demand to accept your answer.

Comment: Politely asking to accept the answer that helped them isn't a bad thing. If there's only one... it's obvious but I don't think it shouldn't be done at all.